# TypeError: Cannot read property 'FieldValue' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

```
  19 | event.preventDefault();
  20 | db.collection('todos').add({
  21 |   todo:input,
  22 |   timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
  23 |  });
  24 | 
  25 | setInput("");
```

Whenever I try to run this code, it shows me type error. So that I cant able to push the data to firebase

Comment: Please edit the question to show how you assigned the value of `firestore`.  Your question should contain enough information that anyone can use to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I get this issue when trying to serve angular ssr build

Answer (score 6):

For those who are using the Admin SDK with NodeJS:

```js
import { FieldValue } from '@google-cloud/firestore'

const docData = {
  userName: 'Lucas'
  createdAt: FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
}
```

You could find all the external API's references here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.firestore

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to import firebase from 'firebase' and not import firebase from './firebase'.

Had the same problem than you, fixed it by doing this.

Comment: This import fix worked for me, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have correct `timestamp` value, or don't pass timestamps if you don't need them. Try passing this json to todos collection:

```
{
  todo:input,
  timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp() || null
}
```

Make sure you have `FieldValue` inside `firebase.firestore` by logging `console.log(firebase.firestore)` and try `console.log(Object.keys(firebase.firestore))`

Comment: I tried it, eventhough its not working. I am getting the same error.

Comment: Explain full error. Edit your question and add full error.

Comment: Paste the console.log value here

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```js
import { serverTimestamp } from '@firebase/firestore'

timestamp: serverTimestamp()
```

I hope it'll work

Answer (score 0):

```
event.preventDefault();
db.collection('todos').add({
  todo:input,
  timestamp: firebase.Xc.firebase_.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
}); 

setInput("");
```

Comment: Please add some explanation. Why do you think your proposed solution might help the OP.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me:

```
const {Timestamp} = require("firebase-admin/firestore")

{
  todo:input,
  timestamp: Timestamp.now(),
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).